# How to read and write (Low Level) raw disk in Windows and Go

Tags: windows, go

I want to know, how should must be access to the raw drive in Windows and Go.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032426/low-level-disk-i-o-in-golang) for Linux, but I ask for Windows.

For example to clear what is ask I need to read and write MBR sector in windows (512 Bytes)

For more clear what I ask, I want to do this on Go
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CCS-LABS-C-Low-Level-Disk-91676ca9 (C#)

Just a little more example code in C

```
HANDLE MasterBootRecord = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,      //Get a handle on the MBR File
    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
```

Final: Read! and Write! raw disk drive in windows. I select to read which sector(s) and write too!

Comment: The linked code is using calls from `Kernel32.dll`, you can do the same using `cgo`. How to actually do that is a bigger question than can be answered sufficiently on SO, you'll probably just have to experiment with it if you can't find any existing resources.