How to read physical disk on windows 10?
I need read physical disk (usb). I want to read/write raw data unallocated area on disk.
Ideally, if there is a solution for Golang. That is, read/write, for example, the first 20 bytes on the disk. Not a logical drive, but a physical one. I understand that this is not safe and low-level, but still.
\\.\PhysicalDriveN not works even with admin privilege.
As far as I understand this is only for Windows 7
I couldn't find any other information

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032426/low-level-disk-i-o-in-golang
